# Elixir - How can you use an alias in doctest?

Tags: testing, elixir

Is there a way to use a module alias in the doctests? I don't want to have to type out a long name every single time.

```
defmodule SomeLongModuleName.SubModule do
  alias SomeLongModuleName.SubModule, as: SubModule

  @doc """
      iex> SubModule.method(%{property_a: 1, property_b: 2) # CompileError
      3
  """
  def method(%{property_a: a, property_b: b) do
    a + b
  end
end
```

The example above shows a situation where I might want to use the alias to avoid long lines. Is it at all possible to use an alias in a doctest?

Comment: I assume that the doctests run from the global namespace, so it won't be able to see the aliases.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are two ways I can think of to not have to type the module name again and again.

1. Use interpolation in your docs and use the aliased name:

   ```
   defmodule SomeLongModuleName.SubModule do
     alias SomeLongModuleName.SubModule, as: SubModule

     @doc """
         iex> #{SubModule}.method(%{property_a: 1, property_b: 2})
         3
     """
     def method(%{property_a: a, property_b: b}) do
       a + b
     end
   end
   ```
2. Use just the function name without module and in your call to `doctest` from your tests, add `import: true`:

   ```
   defmodule SomeLongModuleName.SubModule do
     @doc """
         iex> method(%{property_a: 1, property_b: 2})
         3
     """
     def method(%{property_a: a, property_b: b}) do
       a + b
     end
   end
   ```

   ```
   doctest SomeLongModuleName.SubModule, import: true
   ```

Comment: Nice! The 1st option looks like a (rather neat) hack, and the 2nd option looks like it was made exactly for this case. Maybe switch the order around?

Answer (score 6):

Building on the answer from lab419 and dylanthepiguy:

Module with doctest:

```
defmodule SomeLongModuleName.SubModule do
  @doc """
      iex> SubModule.add(x, y)
      3
  """
  def add(x, y) do
    x + y
  end
end
```

Test case for module with doctest:

```
defmodule SomeLongModuleName.SubModuleTest do
  use ExUnit.Case, async: true

  # Alias the submodule so we don't have to use the fully qualified name 
  alias SomeLongModuleName.SubModule

  doctest SomeLongModuleName.SubModule, import: true
end
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by dylanthepiguy it is definitely a better solution to put the aliases into the testfile, just before the `doctest` line.

Instrumenting your code for tests is IMHO a code smell.

Also note that `as: Submodule` is the default and therefore unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you can put a `alias SomeLongModuleName.SubModule, as: SubModule` line just before the test.

A better solution is to not put too many tests in the docs, and not use an alias. Then, in your test file you can put `alias SomeLongModuleName.SubModule, as: SubModule` to save.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you're asking for, but one approach that is relatively clean and will work regardless of how you invoke `doctest` (doesn't rely on the `import` and the lack of conflicts between imported and existing functions) - alias the module in the doctest itself.

```
defmodule Some.Long.Module.Chain.Foo
  @doc """
      iex> alias Some.Long.Module.Chain.Foo
      iex> Foo.bar(1)
      "one"
      iex> Foo.bar(2)
      "two"
  """
  def bar(i) do
    # ...
  end
end
```